# Replace column values in a dataframe according to a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have dataframe with two columns `Drivers_90_00_Visual` and `"Drivers_00_05_Visual`.

```
dput(list_table_Tanzania_Merge2)
structure(list(Drivers_90_00_Visual = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 
520L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 530L, 520L, 520L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 
0L, 0L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 
100L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 
520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 
100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 
200L, 0L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 
100L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 
0L, 100L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 200L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 
100L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 0L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 240L, 200L, 100L, 240L, 
200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
240L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 100L, 240L, 
520L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 
100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 
100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 240L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
200L, 200L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
520L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 
200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 200L, 520L, 
520L, 999L, 520L, 999L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 999L, 520L, 520L, 
0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 100L, 520L, 
520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
0L, 0L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 100L, 100L, 
200L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 520L, 100L, 520L, 
100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 520L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), Drivers_00_05_Visual = c(520L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 530L, 520L, 
520L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 
520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 0L, 0L, 520L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 0L, 0L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 
0L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 
200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 500L, 520L, 
200L, 500L, 200L, 240L, 520L, 240L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 240L, 600L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 530L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 0L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 240L, 
240L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 500L, 500L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 500L, 500L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 500L, 200L, 
200L, 240L, 240L, 500L, 200L, 240L, 500L, 500L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
520L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 
240L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 500L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 0L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
530L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 0L, 0L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 0L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 200L, 520L, 
240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 240L, 240L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 240L, 
520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 520L, 520L, 200L, 200L, 520L, 
520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L, 520L)), .Names = c("Drivers_90_00_Visual", 
"Drivers_00_05_Visual"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1601L))
```

I want to reclassify some values of the columns according to two conditions. If value= 250,230,240,210 or 220 it will get the value 200 and if value =520 or 530 it will get the value 500.

Comment: Waht about the x= 250,230,240,210? I want to have two conditions in my command line.

Comment: Ok Thanks akrun. it works perfectly. Do you know why list_table_Tanzania_Merge2[] becomes a matrix after the reclassification?

Comment: It didn't.  `str(list_table_Tanzania_Merge2)#'data.frame': 1601 obs. of  2 variables:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
  list_table_Tanzania_Merge2[] <- lapply(list_table_Tanzania_Merge2, 
                                  function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(250,230,240,210,220), 200,
                                           ifelse(x %in% c(520,530), 500, x)))


  str(list_table_Tanzania_Merge2)
  #'data.frame':    1601 obs. of  2 variables:
  #$ Drivers_90_00_Visual: num  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 ...
  #$ Drivers_00_05_Visual: num  500 200 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 ...
```